# Error on writing or trying to change to VS Code settings

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I am getting this error when I try to change my settings
**Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again.**
Perhaps I have stared at this too long, but I dont see where I have an error. If I manually copy a setting over to the file, such as the *"workbench.sideBar.location": "right"* at the bottom,it works fine. Can anyone see my json error here? Version 1.30.0. This was occurring before updating to latest version

```
{
"files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
"editor.fontSize": 18,
"editor.tabSize": 2,
"editor.wordWrap": "on",
"beautify.tabSize": 2,
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"bracketPairColorizer.colorMode": "Independent",
"workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
"workbench.tips.enabled": false,
"editor.parameterHints": false,
"highlight-matching-tag.leftStyle": {
"borderWidth": "0 0 0 3px",
"borderStyle": "dotted",
"borderColor": "yellow",
"borderRadius": "5px"
},
"highlight-matching-tag.rightStyle": {
"borderWidth": "0 3px 0 0",
"borderStyle": "dotted",
"borderColor": "yellowd",
"borderRadius": "5px"
},
"bracketPairColorizer.independentPairColors": [
["()", ["Aqua", "Orchid", "LightSkyBlue"], "Red"],
["[]", ["LightSkyBlue", "Orchid", "yellow"], "Red"],
["{}", ["LightSkyBlue", "Orchid", "Aqua"], "Red"]
],
"bracketPairColorizer.consecutivePairColors": [
["</", ">"],
["<", "/>"],
"<>",
["Gold", "Orchid", "LightSkyBlue"],
"Red"
],
"git.enableSmartCommit": true,
"editor.minimap.enabled": false,
"git.autofetch": true,
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.1.9\\php.exe",
"editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code",
"editor.fontLigatures": true,
"workbench.colorTheme": "Default High Contrast",
"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
"php-cs-fixer.executablePath": "${extensionPath}\\php-cs-fixer.phar",
"php-cs-fixer.lastDownload": 1538537777147,
"phpformatter.pharPath": "php-cs-fixer.phar",
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
"zenMode.hideTabs": false,
"workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
"editor.autoClosingQuotes": "always",
"better-comments.highlightPlainText": true,
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
"javascript",
"HTML"
},
"workbench.sideBar.location": "right",
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need validate the settings.json format, put colons: i.e:

```
{
    "yaml.schemas": {
        "file:///home/yony/.vscode/extensions/docsmsft.docs-yaml-0.2.4/schemas/toc.schema.json": "/toc\\.yml/i"
    },

    "files.associations": {
        "*.erb": "erb"
    },
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "erb": "html"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Yony. I appreciate you

Comment: VS Code 1.47.3 still is unable to produce a valid settings JSON file. Thank you!

Comment: Still facing problem

Answer (score 1):

Change it to *Default* settings and *re-configure* it as you want

**Add** this *default settings* to **your** `settings.json` file

`Simple copy and paste`

[>> Default Settings.json File <<](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings)